# How to get clientSecret when Switching from CardElement to PaymentElement for subscription?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

When using `CardElement` I didn't need to pass `clientSecret` into `Element`, but when switching to `PaymentElement` I am required to pass it.
In the official Stripe example, they only use `paymentIntent`: `const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({...`, but this is for a single payment. What do I need to do to get `clientSecret` when I want to create a new subscription?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, the Payment Element requires a Payment Intent's client-secret in order to be created but Card Element does not require that.

With subscriptions, you’d need to create the pricing model first by using the [Products API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products) and [Prices API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices). Then, create the [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers). From here, on the frontend, you’d pass the price id and the customer id. On the backend, you’d create the [subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create), with status `incomplete` using `payment_behavior` parameter with the value `default_incomplete`. To access the Payment Intent's client-secret, you’ll need to fetch it from your backend and return it to the frontend to complete the Payment Intent. This flow is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements#create-subscription). Also, here is a sample code of how you'd fetch the client-secret:

```
 async function initialize() {
        const response = await fetch("/create-subscription", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify({items}),
        });
        const { clientSecret } = await response.json();
};
```

Finally, this [section](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements#collect-payment) shows an example code of how you’d then pass the client-secret on the frontend to complete the payment for the subscription.